# Adding additional host to Juypterhub DockerSpawner

Tags: docker, jupyterhub

I am using Jupyterhub 0.9.4 with DockerSpawner.
My goal is to pass every container spawned by the Spawner an additional host name, so make an additional entry in `/etc/hosts`.

I first tried via my `docker-compose.yml` file, which does not work, as the container are created by Jupyterhub.

I also tried it in the `Dockerfile` itself, but there it got overwritten.

I further tried it with changes in the `jupyterhub_config.py` file, by adding:
`c.DockerSpawner.extra_create_kwargs.update({'command': '--add-host="<ip-address> <hostname>"'})`

Still I do not see an entry in the `/etc/hosts` file in the container.

Anyone has a clue where I have to add it?

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 5):

You can do the equivalent of `docker run --add-host "foo.domain.local:192.168.1.12" ...` like so:

```
c.DockerSpawner.extra_host_config.update({
  "extra_hosts": {
    "foo.domain.local":"192.168.1.12",
    "other.domain.local":"192.168.1.13"
  }
})
```

I couldn't find that in any documentation.